# Why is a view not filling the entire frame of a scroll view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

thank you for reading.  I appreciate any insights you could share.

I have scroll view.  I call it `myTopScrollView`.

This scroll view has a width of 1024 pts and a height of 340 pts.

It draws the subview of another view controller, which I dragged into Storyboard from the objects library.  I identify this view controller as `topScrollViewPage1`.

I go to the Size Inspector to specify a Frame Rectangle with the width of 1024 pts and a height of 340 pts (see [Figure 1](http://s3.amazonaws.com/pubbuc/Figure1.png))

```
// Point to the main storyboard.
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 

// Point to the first scroll view for myTopScrollView.
UIViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"topScrollViewPage1"];

// Add the subview to the scroll view.
[self.myTopScrollView addSubview:myViewController.view];

// Define the content size - width and height.
self.myTopScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 340);

// Add the scroll view to the view.
[self.view addSubview:self.myTopScrollView];
```

Now, it compiles successfully, and it loads.

However, the subview with a red background does not fill the entire width of the scroll view frame, even though the four buttons I used to mark the four corners of the subview are drawn exactly where I put them in Storyboard (see [Figure 2](http://s3.amazonaws.com/pubbuc/Figure2.png)).

The question is why?

Interestingly, the subview's red background stops at 768 pts (the width length of an iPad in portrait orientation).

This leads me to think maybe this is a default value of a drawing property in a `UIView` or `UIViewController` class.  I am still checking but nothing yet.

Do you know the why the view background is not filling the entire width of the scroll view (even though I specified the `contentSiz`e of the scroll view to be the entire width of 1024 pts)?

Comment: Perhaps the drawing mode should be `redraw`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer has to do with the view controller with identifier, "topScrollViewPage1".

The "Frame Rectangle" size of the view in this view controller was still in the default value.

To change the size of the view, highlight the view controller, go to "Attributes Inspector", under "Size", change "Inferred" to "Freeform".

This will let you change the frame size of the view inside this view controller.